# Is there a way to disconnect from a port, in Selenium, without using cmd or terminal

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Just wondering if there was a way to disconnect from a port without going in the cmd or terminal and entering kill or lsof -i? Can that be added in the editor - maybe as a capability? Currently running automation tests in Selenium - Java - Eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: What does "kill a port" mean?

Comment: meant disconnect from port. updated question

Answer (score -1):

You can close Selenium via the driver by calling the quit method.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit--

```
driver.quit()
```